# Nested scrollview not working below lollipop in Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have created Custom ListView in Xamarin Forms. This list view is inside scrollview. It is working in Iphone but not working for below Lollipop in Android.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not that straightforward to enable support for pre-Lollipop devices. You will need to turn to support libraries. Instead of `ScrollView`, you'll want to use [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html). From there you'll have access to [NestedScrollingParent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingParent.html) and [NestedScrollingChild](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChild.html) that you'll need to use. Refer to the documentation for a description of what they do.

For the ListView, you should use [NestedScrollingChildHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/NestedScrollingChildHelper.html) to make it work correctly inside the `NestedScrollView`.

**Edit:** You can find the `NestedScrollView` from `Android.Support.V4.Widget.NestedScrollView`. Since you're using a custom renderer, you can replace the original `ListView` with `NestedScrollView` for all pre-Lollipop devices.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  NestedScrollView is only available in Xamarin Android but my view is on Forms. So I need a solution that works for Xamarin forms.

Comment: @AjaySharma Basically anything that is available for Android can be accessed using Xamarin.Android (and subsequently Xamarin.Forms). I updated my answer.

Comment: Can you help me out to know that How can we using a custom renderer, you can replace the original ListView with NestedScrollView for all pre-Lollipop devices ?

Comment: @AjaySharma You might need to study custom renderers more. Here's a good starting point: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction/. Anyway, what you need to do is create a new instance of NestedScrollView and `use SetNativeControl(yourNestedScrollView);` to set it as the active control on Android. You'll find more and better explanations on Xamarin's official guides.